# grad of scalar field question

Tags: calculus

**Question**

If $P(r)$ is a point $r = \rho \cos \phi \, \boldsymbol i + \rho \sin \phi \boldsymbol \, \boldsymbol j + z \, \boldsymbol k$ and a scalar field $V = {\rho}^2 \, z \sin(2 \phi)$ exists in space, using cylindrical polar coordinates ($\rho,\phi,z$) determine $\operatorname{grad} V$ at the point at which $\rho = 1, \, \phi = \dfrac{\pi}{4}, \, z = 2$

**My Answer**

Use the standard formula for grad in cylindrical polar coordinates:

$\operatorname{grad} \, V = \dfrac{\partial V}{\partial \rho} \boldsymbol I + \dfrac{1}{\rho} \dfrac{\partial V}{\partial \phi} \boldsymbol J + \dfrac{\partial V}{\partial z} \boldsymbol K$

we get:

$\operatorname{grad} \, V = 2 \, \rho \, z \sin \phi \, \boldsymbol I + \rho \, z \cos \phi \, \boldsymbol J + \rho^2 \sin \phi \, \boldsymbol K$

and substituting in the values of $\rho = 1, \, \phi = \dfrac{\pi}{2} \, \text{ and }\, z = 2$ gives:

$\operatorname{grad} \, V = \dfrac{4}{\sqrt{2}} \boldsymbol I \, + \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{2}} \boldsymbol J \, + \, \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \boldsymbol K$

**Book Answer**

$4 \boldsymbol I \, + \, \boldsymbol K$

I've not used the point P(r) in any way. How have I misunderstood the question?

Thanks,
Mitch.

Comment: What happens to $2\phi$ in the sin? Does the two get eaten up? Do it once again more carefully and think of all the rules of differentiation.

Answer (score 1):

$\nabla V = \left( \frac{\partial V}{\partial \rho},\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\partial V}{\partial \phi}, \frac{\partial V}{\partial z}\right) = \operatorname{grad} V = \left(2 \rho z \sin 2 \phi, 2 \rho z \cos 2 \phi, \rho ^2 \sin 2 \phi  \right)$.

Substituting $\rho = 1, \phi = \frac{\pi}{4}, z=2$, we get:

$\nabla V\left(1,\frac{\pi}{4},2\right) = (4,0,1)$.

I think the mention of $P(\mathbf{r})$ is just to make it clear that we're in cylindrical coordinates - it's just the Cartesian coordinates $(x,y,z)$ expressed in terms of $\rho,\phi,z$ i.e. $x = \rho \cos \phi, \ y = \rho \sin \phi, \ z=z$.

Comment: OK, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all.

I see that when I wrote the question down I wrote $V=\rho^2 \, z \, sin \, \theta$ instead of $V=\rho^2 \, z \, sin \, 2\theta$

Your answers helped me to see that. I looked straight through the typo :(

Thanks.

I don't see the reason for the question mentioning P(r).